# MySQL find top results for each group

Tags: mysql, database, select, greatest-n-per-group

I have searched a lot, but I can't find an answer or something near.

I have a table like this:

```
id              int(11) NO  PRI     auto_increment
attribute_id    int(11) YES         
user_id         int(11) YES         
result          int(11) YES             
x10             int(11) YES
```

I need about 5 results from each `attribute_id`.

`attribute_id` can be any number, so at first, I need to check for the `attribute_id`, and next I have to check for the results for each attribute_id.

I can't find out how I do this without any programming language other than MySQL, but I know you can.

Example:

```
attribute_id    result
1               200
1               149
1               123
2               322
2               321
2               300
3               ...
3               ...
```

And so on.

Comment: in short, do you want to get the first five highes result for every attribute_ID?

Comment: Did you read about `UNION`

Comment: Is I want to get the five heighst for each attribute_id

Comment: Yes i read about UNION but if I use Union then I have to create each SELECT statements, but not possible, while I have about 50 attribute_IDs

Comment: I don't believe that the OP has provided adequate information to answer this question.

Comment: Well, JW get it , and his answer was what I'm looking for. A little bit slow, but again, it's because of my requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  attribute_id, result
FROM    TableName a
WHERE 
        (
            SELECT  COUNT(*) 
            FROM    TableName b
            WHERE   a.attribute_id = b.attribute_id 
                    AND a.result <= b.result
        ) <= 5
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bfd3e/2)

Answer (score 0):

```
     SELECT     attribute_id, result
     FROM   TableName a
      WHERE 
    (
        SELECT  COUNT(*) 
        FROM    TableName b
        WHERE   a.attribute_id = b.attribute_id 
                AND a.result <= b.result
    ) <= 5 order by result DESC;
```